# My Jupyter Notebook doesn't work properly

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

It worked well yesterday on Windows.

But in the morning today when I ran Jupyter in my environment and Chrome showed up, it didn't show anything but white.

Like this:

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbaXT.png) and [Cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfojo.png).

I turned off the firewall, checked my hosts and runned

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterhub
```

But nothing happend.

I'm new so I don't know how to deal with it. I'll appreciate it if someone could help me out.

---

***I find that I can run my jupyter if I click the shortcut "Jupyter Notebook" but I can't run it in my environment.*** Why?

Comment: Did you start jupyter with `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Yes with cmd in my virtual environment.

Comment: Did you try the last link in your cmd image?

Comment: Clear the browsing history and cookies in the browser. It'll work.

Comment: that link should look something like `http://localhost:8888/?token=[gibberish]`

Comment: I think it's not getting the path...
Try to reinstall.

Comment: You should try to open the those given links on other browsers like Firefox, Edge, etc.

Comment: Thanks but cleaning up the history and cookies doesn't woke.

Comment: I tried the link.

Comment: what does the last line of the terminal say, in which you started jupyter?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/?token=acc47cb1350676571c552aa12e8a7c95b89c828672c5875d

Comment: Referring to your edit, which shortcut works? Shortcut to the command prompt? Shortcut to conda prompt? Shortcut to browser? When you get the blank browser screen, what happens if you try to navigate to the url `localhost:8888/tree` ?

Comment: The shortcut of "Jupyter Notebook" works. But if I run the jupyter notebook installed in my environment it goes wrong. If I try to navigate to that url nothing happens, just blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Here is the link

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467

The reason is that I'm using a newer version of Jupyter installed by command

```
conda install jupyter
```

which causes the trouble.