# Jupyter notebook shows blank page in browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am launching a Jupyter notebook from an Anaconda environment (Python 3.6.8) on Windows 10 and when I do that the page that's displayed in my Chrome browser is totally blank.

The output in the console (git bash) window looks like this:

```
$ jupyter notebook object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
[I 13:18:13.500 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\home\git\object_detection_tensorflow\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection
[I 13:18:13.500 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 13:18:13.500 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=bfb419ee35f8fd9800621e52dc8d73515990e2298148135b
[I 13:18:13.500 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:18:13.513 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/James%20Adams/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2808-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=bfb419ee35f8fd9800621e52dc8d73515990e2298148135b
```

If I copy and paste the URL listed above into the Chrome browser address bar I get a normal looking response in the console but the same blank page in the browser:

```
[I 13:21:17.840 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=bfb419ee35f8fd9800621e52dc8d73515990e2298148135b (::1) 0.99ms
```

I have tried a number of things with no different result so far:

- clear the browser's cache and cookies
- downgraded the notebook module to 5.7.4 (`conda install notebook=5.7.4`)
- used a different browser (Firefox)

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: I have managed to get around this by using another port number other than the default 8888 (I used 8889). I first ran `jupyter notebook stop 8888` but it reported "There are no running servers" so that may not have been necessary. I then ran `jupyter notebook --port=8889` and the notebook appeared as expected. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Here's on recent post of a similar nature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253094/my-jupyter-notebook-doesnt-work-properly/55254346#55254346. Not sure if it will be useful to you.

Comment: The thread I mentioned above seems to conclude (looking at the gitub conversation), that version 5.7.5 of Jupyter notebook works. Did that version work for you?

Comment: Thanks @fountainhead. I have not had luck so far by downgrading to a previous version of the notebook package. When I look at the developer tools console in Chrome I see messages like this: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js?v=f004a16cb856e0ff11781d01ec5ca8fe' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.